# Ws-federation dotnet core not doing anything with wsignoutcleanup1.0

Tags: .net-core, ws-federation

I'm attempting to configure an application to leverage federated logins with .NET Core. I see that my client application is sending wsignin1.0 and wsignout1.0 messages to the federated provider. However, when I attempt to send a wsignoutcleanup1.0 to my client application, nothing happens. How do federated clients receive wsignoutcleanup messages to clear their session state?

Here is my wsfederation configuraiton for my client:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
         sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }
    ).AddCookie(options =>
    {
         options.Cookie.Name = "TestStsAuth1";
    }).AddWsFederation(options =>
    {
        WsFederationConfiguration configuration = new WsFederationConfiguration();
        configuration.Issuer = "http://localhost/STSSpike2/V1";
        configuration.TokenEndpoint = "http://localhost/STSSpike/V1";
        options.Configuration = configuration;
        options.Wtrealm = "http://localhost/STSAwareApp2/Test";
        options.SecurityTokenHandlers.Add(new FakeTokenValidator());
        options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
        options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/Logout";

     });

     services.AddLogging(
               builder =>
               {
                   builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Trace)
                           .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Trace)
                           .AddConsole();
               });
        }
```

I have attempted to send GET requests to /Logout with wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0, but I don't seem to see the Cookie for the session getting cleaned up, nor do I see the WsFederataion.OnRemoteSignOut event getting fired. Any pointers on what I am missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

Recommended closing question. The remote signout event was being invoked. End user error